# Smooth image contours using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I applied some operations on the image to remove the white background(color clustering), but the issue is that the result is not smooth on the contours as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf0Pi.jpg.

What's your advice for smoothing the contours without blurring the entire image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this doesn't sound like a repetitive job. how often do you need this?

Comment: Everytime an user upload an image where the background is not transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to solve my problem. The first step is to approximate the contours using approxPolyDp(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c). The second step is to have a gradual transparency on the contours.

The results are not perfect for each image, but it's a lot cleaner.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called *image matting*. The basic idea is to determine the amount of background color (white) present in the pixel and to replace it with black. This will anti-alias the outlines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a look to the image matting algorithm( http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/anat.levin/papers/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf), and I also found some code in python(https://github.com/MarcoForte/closed-form-matting). I tried, but after applying the resulted mask on the image(the mask become the alpha channel of the image), the aliasing is unfortunately still here ...  I may have to investigate more on that

Comment: @pensfute: did you really remove the white ?

Comment: What do you mean by removing? I made it transparent on the alpha channel yes, but of course he is still here

Comment: You must modify the color of the pixels, not the transparency.

Comment: hmmmm I'm not sure I understand your point.  I think I was not clear, my final goal is to make the white pixels transparent.  Sorry if I'm too slow to understand, thanks for your time.

Comment: Image matting need a tripmap to work. So what I do, I obtain a first segmentation version by using kmeans to cluster colors which I can use to create a binary mask for foreground/background. Then I apply erosion on this mask  to have the uncertain part of the image(mostly contours); I give this trimap to the algorithm(image matting) with the real image and the algorithm return the alpha which I use to make the background transparent. When and why do you want me to change the colors of the white pixel?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple Bilateral filter could do the job. You can also try more advanced filters like [Total Variation Denoising](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.denoise_tv_chambolle).

Keep in mind that this process is never going to be perfect if your input images are very different from each other.

Comment: Never answer without taking a look at the images.